# Evaluation of integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xe^{-|x|}\,dx$ is not $0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given $$f(x)=\frac12e^{-|x|},  -\infty \le x \le +\infty$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x f(x)\, dx= -\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x (-e^{-|x|})' dx=-\frac12\bigg(-xe^{-|x|} + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-|x|} dx\bigg) $$
$$=\frac12(xe^{-|x|}+e^{-|x|}|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}) = \frac12xe^{-|x|}$$

I know the final result is not correct, but help me on this as I am unable to resolve it by any means.

Comment: $e^{-|x|}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: The form of the antiderivative of $e^{-|x|}$ is not the same for positive and negative values of x.

Comment: The answer should be $0$. The integrand is an odd function. You may need to consider the principle value.

Comment: The value of a definite integral with respect to $x$ will never be a function of $x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Mhenni: There is no need to consider the principal value. This function is unconditionally integrable over any interval in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is $0$ if the you consider a symmetric interval $[-N,N]$!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : But that proves at most that a principal value is $0$.  Similarly, you can say that $\displaystyle\int_{-N}^N \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}=0$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^N \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{2N} \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}$ are two different numbers, both finite. Your method doesn't prove that that doesn't happen with the integral in this question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: There is no issue here! I know what you mean! The integral converges to $0$ without considering the principle value. That's why I said "You may need...". I already pointed the main point which is the integrand is an odd integrable function. Right!

Comment: @TonyK: Are you following my comments and answers and becoming so fussy! What's going on with you people?

Comment: @Mhenni Don't worry, I'm not stalking you. Your suggestion of using the principal value was simply unnecessary, so I said so. With your rep, you should be able to handle it.

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks for pointing this out! But as I said "you may need... ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x \Big( e^{-x}\,dx\Big) & = \int x\,dv = xv-\int v\,dx \\[8pt]
& = \left.-xe^{-x}\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty -e^{-x}\,dx \\[8pt]
& = \left.\left(-xe^{-x} - e^{-x}\right)\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_0^\infty.
\end{align}

It is easy to evaluate this expression at $x=0$.  To "evaluate it at $\infty$" is to find its limit as $x\to\infty$.  In the case of the second term that is clearly $0$.  The first term can be handled by L'Hopital's rule applied to $x/e^x$.

L'Hopital's rule often gives answers very fast without giving insight.  You might think about a common sense reason why you would expect $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x/e^x$ to be $0$ by means having nothing to do with L'Hopital's rule.

So we see that the integral above is $1$.  In the same way, we can see that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 x e^x\,dx=-1.
$$
Consequently
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-|x|}\,dx = 1 + (-1).
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\mathrm{e}^{-|x|}dx & = \int_{-\infty}^{0}x\mathrm{e}^{x}dx + \int^{\infty}_{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx \\[6pt]
& =\int_{\infty}^{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx + \int^{\infty}_{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx \\[6pt]
& =-\int^{\infty}_{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx + \int^{\infty}_{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx \\[6pt]
& =0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Cheers for the edit.

Comment: Why $\int_{-\infty}^{0}x\mathrm{e}^{x}dx = \int_{\infty}^{0}x\mathrm{e}^{-x}dx$?

Comment: because i made the sub $x\rightarrow -x$ and then $$\int_{b}^{a}\rightarrow -\int_{a}^{b}$$.

Answer (score 2):

When you evaluate $x e^{-|x|}$ in $x=\pm\infty$ you get zero.

By the way, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-|x|}\,dx = 0$$
since $x e^{-|x|}$ is an odd function that belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: What's $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @canoe: the space of Lebesgue integrable functions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @canoe : $L^1(\mathbb R)$ is the set of functions $f$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|\,dx<\infty$ (note the absolute value).  That's the same as saying the positive and negative parts are both finite.